# injection with spring in the managed bean :

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I created a simple application that s using JSF and managed beans.From the managed bean I m trying to instantiate a spring bean that stores data to the database. However "**@Autowired**" annotation doesnt seem to work since I get a **nullPointerExcpetion**:

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException

The problem appears when there invocation **authenticationComponent.authenticate ()** method

***rmq*** : I tested the methods of ClientService and all is well

managed bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="authenticationComponent")
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticationComponent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5085727127290746426L;
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String ERROR = "error";

    @Autowired
    ClientService clientService;
    Client client;
    String clientName;
    String clientPass;
    public String authenticate() {

        client = clientService.authenticate(clientName, clientPass);
        if (client != null) {
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;

    }
```

authentification.xhtml

> ```
>               <p:inputText id="userName"  required="true"
>                   label="User Name" title="Enter Your Name !" value="#{authenticationComponent.clientName}"/>
>               <p:tooltip for="userName" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus"
>                   hideEvent="blur" />
>
>               <h:panelGroup>
>                   <h:outputText value="User Password : " />
>                   <h:outputText style="color:red" value="* " />
>               </h:panelGroup>
>
>               <p:inputText id="userPass"  required="true"
>                   label="User Password" title="Enter Your Password !" value="#{authenticationComponent.clientPass}" />
>                   <!-- 
>                           label option is needed for messages component
>                    -->
>               <p:tooltip for="userPass" styleClass="tooltip" showEvent="focus"
>                   hideEvent="blur" />
>
>               <p:commandButton id="submitLoginButton"
>                   update="loginPanelGrid,messages" value="Sign In"
>                   icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{authenticationComponent.authenticate()}" />
>               <p:commandButton id="newUserButton"
>                   update="loginPanelGrid,messages" value="Sign Up"
>                   icon="ui-icon-plus"  />
> ```

applicationContext:

```
    <bean id="clientService" class="com.webapp.service.ClientServiceImpl">
            <property name="clientDao" ref="clientDao" />
        </bean>
 <bean id="genericDao" class="com.webapp.dao.GenericDaoImpl" abstract="true" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDao" class="com.webapp.dao.ClientDaoImpl" parent="genericDao">
        <constructor-arg ref="client"  />
   </bean>

  <bean id="client" class="com.webapp.model.Client"/>
```

Comment: You are confusing JSF managed beans with spring beans. @Autowired won't be detected by spring because the bean is being created out of the application context by the JSF framework.

Comment: thank you, use what then to inject ClientService ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need a custom el-resolver in your `faces-config.xml` file:

```
 <application>
        <!-- For DI of beans from Spring WebApplicationContext -->
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Then you will need to use the annotation `@ManagedProperty` like this:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{clientService}")
ClientService clientService;
```

So the spring el-resolver can inject your service bean by name.

Comment: i have this this error : Error Rendering View [/ welcome.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Unable to create managed "authenticationComponent" bean. The following problems were detected:
      - The "ClientService" property of the managed bean "authenticationComponent" does not exist.

Comment: Did you created the clientService getter and setter? Test then.